# WP Elementor: Set section layout from "boxed" to "full width" as default statement

Tags: wordpress, elementor

By default the Elementor PageBuilder in WordPress pages comes with a section inner widget and the default setting is "boxed". The page width is always limited for e.g. 1200 px. There is always a padding on right and left side when the desktop is more the 1200 px.

I want to change the default setting and set the "boxed" setting to "full width". Therefore the content area is strength and no padding on left and right side.

Is there any hook i can use in elementor to edit the section layout?

[image]

Comment: you can use the elementor/frontend/section/should_render filter to change the default section layout from "boxed" to "full width"

Comment: can you make an example? i have the opportunity to add a class but i cannot find a solution to update the value "layout" to full width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the elementor/frontend/section/should_render filter to change the default section layout from "boxed" to "full width":

```
function my_elementor_section_layout( $should_render, $elementor_section ) {
    if ( 'boxed' === $elementor_section->get_settings( 'layout' ) ) {
        $elementor_section->set_settings( 'layout', 'full_width' );
    }
    return $should_render;
}
add_filter( 'elementor/frontend/section/should_render', 'my_elementor_section_layout', 10, 2 );
```